# How to add <tr> and </tr> in different if()

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

As the Title i would like to add  and  in different if().

Here is my code:

```
        @foreach(var v in Model)
        {
            @if (v.GroupID != g)
            {
                **<tr>**
                g = v.GroupID
            }
            @if (v.GroupID != g)
            { 
                **</tr>**
                g = v.GroupID
            }
        }
```

I am using `MVC razor` and i'm really new in it.

Comment: because you asked this, I would strongly recommend  to refer      @MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.HtmlOutput) -- < MVC 4 | 
@(new HtmlString("<tr">)) | 
@Html.Raw("<tr>")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@:` to specify some generic non-C# text. You can use HTML with this technique.

```
@foreach(var v in Model)
{
    @if (v.GroupID != g)
    {
        @:<tr>
        g = v.GroupID
    }
    .
    .
    .
    @if (v.GroupID != g)
    { 
        @:</tr>
        g = v.GroupID
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@foreach (var v in Model)
{
    if (v.GroupID != g)
    {
    <tr>
        g = v.GroupID
    </tr>
    }
    if (v.GroupID != g)
    { 
    <tr>
        g = v.GroupID
    </tr>
    }
}
```